# When I run my program I get "a referral was returned from the server" in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I did a lot of searching on this error and was confused when every single thing related to this has to do with AD.

First off let me just say, that my program runs from within VS 2013 with no problems whatsoever, whether it be in debug or release.

However when I run my program after rebuilding my program from the release folder I get an error saying "a referral was returned from the server".

My program doesn't have anything to do with AD.

Is there anything else other than AD that can give me this error? Most of the things I read up on they were giving specific lines that were causing the error during runtime, mine does only when not running in VS.

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thank you.

Comment: What does your program do? are you authenticating a user somewhere? have you added logging to see where the referral occurs?

Comment: http://www.hartechsoftworks.com/a-referral-was-returned-from-the-server/ is your app unsigned and trying to run elevated?

Comment: Please **show us** some of your code! What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think its to do with uac and elevation - remember VS normally runs as admin...

Comment: Ty, I added a new app manifest that has it run elevated! I had forgotten I had done that. Again thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error when I changed the requestedPrivileges in the application manifest file. I changed the uiAccess to true on the requestExectionLevel node. Reverting this change solved my problem. Level of the requestedExecutionLevel was set to "highestAvailable".

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because you have the UAC enabled and a local group policy called `Only elevate executables that are signed and validated` also enabled.

Go to the Group Policy Editor > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options and set `User Account Control: Only elevate executables that are signed and validated` to `Disabled`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add a post-build event to sign the resulting .exe

Previously only the .dll was being signed